# Change SelectionSet of SharePoint PeopleEditor control on codebehind

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have to change the SelectionSet of a PeopleEditor on codebehind based on the selection of a dropdownlist. What happens is that after it's changed from User to SPGroup, when I click "browse" I can search sharepoint groups with no problem, but when I add a group and click "check names" then it doesn't resolve it, the control keeps resolving only users.

Code:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="peDestinatarios" runat="server" AfterCallbackClientScript="updateValidation('peDestinatarios');"
                                MultiSelect="true" SelectionSet="User" class="validate[funcCall[validateEmptyPicker]]" />

    protected void ddlType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlType.SelectedValue == "Users")
        {
            peDestinatarios.SelectionSet = "User";
        }
        else if (ddlType.SelectedValue == "Groups")
        {
            peDestinatarios.SelectionSet = "SPGroup";
        }

        peDestinatarios.CommaSeparatedAccounts = string.Empty;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This may be silly but has your ddlType been set to `AutoPostBack="true"`?

Comment: Yes, the postback is being done, also the change appears to be working partially, because the Browse window is showing the groups (as it's supposed to) but the validation is still working for users

Comment: Then you might have been victim of the page lifecycle and how the PeopleEditor was built (in that, it looks for SelectionSet property before you set it on your postback method), you could try to trigger the init/load for the control again, but I'd recommend replacing the control from the page/usercontrol with a placeholder and then re-creating it entirely on the codebehind everytime the type is changed, since you are resetting the value you should be OK doing this.